# Send text updates from website?

Tags: email, sms

So say a website has been updated, or some such statistic was put in (by a third party). Now, if I wanted to get this statistic sent to my phone (and this wasn't an option on the website), what would I do?

Comment: You'd write code to monitor the site, and use something like https://www.twilio.com/ to send the SMSes.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination would be to check if this site has a public API to pull information from.  If that is so, you could make a server application that polls the API and sends you the data through an sms service like [twillio](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/).
I think this would be the most simple and straightforward approach.